# ошибка при отправке письма ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, sendmail, syntax

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться.

На сайте имеется форма обратной связи, посылающая `post` средствами `ajax`. Суть в том, что форма отправляется, получатель письмо получает, но почему-то срабатывает параметр `error` у `ajax`.

В консоли ошибка синтаксиса `SyntaxError` (скрин прилагаю).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$('.call_block button').on('click', function() {
  var data = $('.call_form').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'callback.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('.call_block button').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function(data) {
      $('.call_block button').button('reset');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('.call_form input.error').removeClass('error');
      $('.call_form .error_span').remove();
      if (data.status == 0) {
        $.each(data.html, function(index, value) {
          $('[name=\"' + index + '\"]').addClass('error');
          $('[name=\"' + index + '\"]').after(value);
        });
      } else {
        $('.call_form').empty();
        $('.call_form').append(data.html);
        $('.call_form').append(data.botton);
      }
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
      $('body').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Ошибка при отправки формы <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что в консоли браузера?

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log("success handler");
  console.log(typeof data);
  console.log(data);
  ...
},
error: function(request, status, error) {
  console.log("error handler");
  console.log(request.responseText);
  console.log(request);
```

В ответе вместо JSON-а - HTML.

Comment: имеете ввиду dataType: "html" ?

Comment: @rabbit Я не знаю, что Вы присылаете с сервера в ответ на ajax запрос.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]решил сам:

- dataType: "json" на "text";
- if (data.status == 0)... на !==0

Comment: Это неправильно. У строки нет свойства `status`.

Comment: Я знаю, что не неправильно. Но к другому решению не могу пока прийти :-(

Comment: Я Вам задал вопрос - что внутри `request`? Но Вы не захотели отвечать.

Comment: Вводимые данные

Comment: Посмотрите на мой ответ. Вам нужна помощь или нет?

Comment: Нужна. Вставил Ваш код в success и error. То, что в консоли на скрине моего ответа.

Comment: Так какие сейчас параметры вызова `$.ajax`? Какой обработчик выполняется? Какая ошибка?

Comment: Прошу прощения за долгий ответ. Ошибка - SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at n.parseJSON (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)
    at Xb (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)
    at y (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)